# Flutter: error when combining charts and animations package

Tags: flutter, dart

In my Flutter app I am using the [animations](https://pub.dev/packages/animations) package. I use the [OpenContainer](https://pub.dev/documentation/animations/latest/animations/OpenContainer-class.html) to open a new window with a nice animation. However, in this window I am using [charts_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/charts_flutter) to, of course, draw a chart. The problem is when the user returns to the previous screen by reversing the OpenContainer animation, the chart throws an error stating:

> 'package:charts_common/src/chart/layout/layout_manager_impl.dart': Failed assertion: line 115 pos 12: '_drawAreaBoundsOutdated == false': is not true.

I think that the cause of this is that the chart is still displaying itself while it's animating so that it would be drawing outside of its bounds.

I've been searching for a few hours and I can't seem to find a solution for this problem.
Does anyone know an answer for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also got that issue with same environment that you have(OpenContainer with charts_flutter package). i removed OpenContainer widget for this chart screen. then it worked fine. as a temporary solution you can fix it like this.
this problem still in under open status https://github.com/google/charts/issues/118